# How can I skip all tests cases in a specific module?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have module named `masterchief.py`.  All of its test cases are located in `test_masterchief.py`. How can I skip **all** test cases in the module?

I understand I can use `unittest.skip` on the classes in the test case module, like this:

```
import unittest

@unittest.skip("My reason for skipping the test cases")
class MasterChief__function1_Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    # <test cases here>
```

However, I have many test case classes in the module, so it will take a lot of copying/pasting to skip them all.  Hence, I'd like to find a way to skip the entire module `test_masterchief.py`.

[edit]

I understand I can do a search and replace, but I'm wondering if PyUnit or Django unit tests, provide a special function (like `skip`), which allows me to skip the entire module by adding one statement.

Comment: Did you tried removing "test" from the file name ?

Comment: In vim, you would be able to accomplish it with search and replace

Comment: @Umair I understand removing "test" from the file name will disable all tests in the file, but that is not an acceptable solution for my situation.

Comment: @postoronnim I understand how to perform a search and replace.  I can also do the same using most any IDE.  However, I was hoping there is some special function in `PyUnit` that allows me to skip the entire module with one statement.